# Can conduit be laid on the ground under a low deck?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel, conduit, hot-tub

I'm planning my run from my main breaker panel to a hot tub subpanel. all wiring will be in PVC conduit. At first, the plan was to bury the entire run. However, as it turns out I could greatly shorten the run by running it under my ~1-2 foot elevated deck. The problem I have since the deck is so low, I can't dig a trench under the deck.

Can I simply lay the conduit on the ground for the run that would only be under the deck?

Comment: The main thing is that the cable/conduit needs to be rated for burial.

Comment: I would attach the conduit to the deck framing, not lay it on the ground.

Answer (score 7):

The deck acts as the protection required by code. You could even use UF under the deck without conduit.

The conduit would be needed prior to exiting from underneath the deck.

Make sure you use a wet rated conductor. Most THHN is dual-rated, as is THWN. This is important because conduit outside is identified by code as a wet location.

Comment: One drawback to UF laying on the ground - critters might decide that it would make a suitable lunch. If one does, you'll know exactly which one, but you'll still have to repair the cable run.

Comment: I would staple the UF to the bottom of the deck.  That's how it's run for my dock lift, though under a dock, instead of a deck.

Comment: Use the conduit , rodents seem to like chewing plastic insulation so it must be protected.

Comment: Yeah, but they like chewing PVC conduit also.  OP can't use metal conduit (most is steel, and ferrous metal disturbs fae folk.  Bronze conduit can be had but is over the moon on cost.)

Comment: I have seen UF on the ground outlast the decking in one case it was composite another it was cedar that the owner did not use pressure treated for the framing , I hear folks talk about mice chewing cables but have rarely seen this in attics and do not ever remember UF being chewed by mice rats or squirrels.